# var numbers = List.generate(10, (i) => i);

Tags: flutter, dart

i just started dart and flutter.

While i studying dart language I saw code like this

```
var numbers = List.generate(10, (i) => i);
```

What is (10, (i) => i) mean?

I guess 10 means generate 10 list, but I have no idear with `(i) => i`

Comment: `(i) => i` creates an anonymous function. `(i)` is the parameter list (it has one parameter), and `=> i` means that the anonymous function returns `i`.  See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#anonymous-functions

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to read the help for [this topic](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List-class.html).

Second, `10` is the length (number of elements) for your new list. `i` is the index for current element being processed, so if the length is `10` then the range for your index is `0..9`. In your code, your new List contains 10 integer elements. So,

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

If your code was like this `var numbers = List.generate(10, (i) => i+3);` your list would be:

```
numbers = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```